# Spring boot - image upload failed

Tags: file, spring-boot, path, upload

Im working on uploading images with spring but I get error when I try save file in one of my projects folder.

Errors:

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: \resources\images\photo001.png
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
\resources\images\photo001.png
```

I have this path:

```
 String path = "\\resources\\images\\";
 String path2 = "c:\\temp\\";
```

Path2 works but I would like to save my files in project without passing whole path starting from C:...

What pass should I pass to save it in resources/images in my project?
My project looks like that:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/mKfpq.png

Comment: are you planning to load file from your project or from any directory which might exist outside your project?

Answer (score 0):

Try 'images/'

All files in src/main/resources are copied into classes/ so in your jar or war there is no folder /resources.

You also should not use the windows specific backslash '\' instead use the 
Use /images/ instead this makes your build portable so it can run on Linux also.

Answer (score 0):

Senio, if you are using Spring Boot then there is a project called [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/) that will allow you to create an image store in very few lines of code.

All you would need to do is add the following Spring Content dependencies  (assuming maven):-

```
<dependencies>
    <!-- Standard Spring Boot -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring Content -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-fs-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-content-rest-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

In your Spring Boot Application class, create an ImageStore interface. Annotate it as a REST resource.  This causes Spring Content to inject an implementation (of this interface for the filesystem) as well as REST endpoints saving you from having to write any this code yourself:-

```
    @SpringBootApplication 
    public class DemoApplication {

        public static void main(String[] args) {        
           SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);  
        }

        @StoreRestResource(path="images")   
        public interface ImageStore extends Store<String> {} 
    }
```

By default Spring Content FS will create a store under java.io.tmpdir.  So you will also need to set the SPRING_CONTENT_FS_FILESYSTEM_ROOT environment variable to point to the root of your "store"; c:\temp\resources\images.

Start the application and you will be able to upload images by POSTing (or PUTting) to:-

> /images/some/path/image-1.jpg

(This also supports GET (download) and DELETE.)

You'll find uploaded images under c:\temp\resources\images\some\path\image-1.jpg

HTH